# Updating SQL from one from one table to another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a question in SQL server , suppose I have two tables one is family and another is individual
as this :
individual table
id (int)PK- Gender- Family_ID(FK_tblfamily)
family table
id (int)PK - total_ind (newly created equl to NULL)

How can I find the sum of family_id from individual for each individual in the table and update total_ind in family table ?

Comment: Would you be so kind to show some sample data and desired output

Comment: For future reference, post actual, executable DDL to illustrate your environment rather than pseudo-code that is poorly formatted.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you'd have 1 record per individual and those individuals would have a common Family_Id.  So, you'd only need to count the rows.  There doesn't appear to be a column you are summing the total of.

So group by that Family_Id and just count the rows from the Individual Table.

Something like this should work:

```
UPDATE FamilyTable
    SET Total_Ind = COUNT(IndividualTable.Id)
FROM FamilyTable
LEFT JOIN IndividualTable
    ON FamilyTable.id = IndividualTable.Family_ID
GROUP BY IndividualTable.Family_ID
```